# Twilio IP Address Control List for sending SMS/MMS messages

Tags: twilio, access-control

We want to use Twilio to send SMS/MMS messages. It's likely that we'll make API calls to Twilio from more than one of our public IP addresses.

Does Twilio have IP Address Control List for sending SMS/MMS, or it doesn't have any restriction on the IP addresses from which the API calls are made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not have restrictions on the IP addresses you can send API calls from, just go right ahead and start sending them!